# C# .NET StreamWriter: How to skip lines when writing file using StreamWriter?

Tags: c#, .net, file-io, streamreader, streamwriter

I read in a text file using StreamReader.
I want to write out this same text file EXCEPT its first 4 lines and its last 6 lines.

How do I do this? Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/931976/is-there-an-option-go-to-line-in-textreader-streamreader

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
string[] fileLines = File.ReadAllLines(@"your file path"); 

var result = fileLines.Skip(4).Take(fileLines.Length - (4 + 6));

File.WriteAllLines(@"your output file path", result);
```

Comment: For completeness, should mention that `Skip` and `Take` are Linq extensions.

Answer (score 3):

Doesn't appear to be the shortest way... but it works for me... Hope it provides some insight.

```
        System.IO.StreamReader input = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"originalFile.txt");
        System.IO.StreamWriter output = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"outputFile.txt");

        String[] allLines = input.ReadToEnd().Split("\n".ToCharArray());

        int numOfLines = allLines.Length;
        int lastLineWeWant = numOfLines - (6);                  //The last index we want. 

        for (int x = 0; x < numOfLines; x++)
        {
            if (x > 4 - 1 && x < lastLineWeWant)  //Index has to be greater than num to skip @ start and below the total length - num to skip at end.
            {
                output.WriteLine(allLines[x].Trim());  //Trim to remove any \r characters.
            }
        }

        input.Close();
        output.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

`StreamReader.ReadLine()` reads file line by line and you can build an array of strings from the file. Then delete first four and last 6 lines from the array. 
And with `StreamWriter.WriteLine()` you can populate new file line by line taking from your array. Should be quite simple.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the easiest way to do it in VB.NET:

```
Private Sub ReplaceString()
    Dim AllLines() As String = File.ReadAllLines("c:\test\myfile.txt")
    For i As Integer = 0 To AllLines.Length - 1
        If AllLines(i).Contains("foo") Then
            AllLines(i) = AllLines(i).Replace("foo", "boo")
        End If
    Next
    File.WriteAllLines("c:\test\myfile.txt", AllLines)
End Sub
```